# unexpected numeric constant graph

Tags: r, graph

The requirement is using R base function to build up a function like this:

Function - is_isomorphic

Input - g1, a graph object; g2, a graph object.

Output - true if g1 and g2 are isomorphic, false if not.

Description - Check if the graph objects are isomorphic, meaning all vertices, edges, and weights are identical. Comparison of vertices should be based on names not indexes, indexes should only be used if vertex labels are not defined.

My code is as follows:

```
isomorphic <- function(g1,g2){
  ##first calculate number of vertices, if not equal, return false
  if(length(g1) != length(g2)){
    return FALSE
  ##then compare each vertix and its related edges and weights
  } else {
    for(i in 1:length(g1)){
      for(j in 1:length(g2)){
        if(names(g1[i]) == names(g2[j]){
          flag = 1
          if(g1[[i]]$edges != g2[[j]]$edges){
              return FALSE            
          } else {
            if(g1[[i]]$weights != g2[[j]]$weights){
              return FALSE
            } else {
              return TRUE
            }
          }
        }   
      }

      if(flag != 1){
        return FALSE
      }
    }    
  }  
}

wrong message: 
isomorphic <- function(g1,g2){
+   ##first calculate number of vertices, if not equal, return false
+   if(length(g1) != length(g2)){
+     return FALSE
Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"  if(length(g1) != length(g2)){
    return FALSE"
>   ##then compare each vertix and its related edges and weights
>   } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>     for(i in 1:length(g1)){
+       for(j in 1:length(g2)){
+         if(names(g1[i]) == names(g2[j]){
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"      for(j in 1:length(g2)){
        if(names(g1[i]) == names(g2[j]){"
>           flag = 1
>           if(g1[[i]]$edges != g2[[j]]$edges){
+               return FALSE            
Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"          if(g1[[i]]$edges != g2[[j]]$edges){
              return FALSE"
>           } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "          }"
>             if(g1[[i]]$weights != g2[[j]]$weights){
+               return FALSE
Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"            if(g1[[i]]$weights != g2[[j]]$weights){
              return FALSE"
>             } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "            }"
>               return TRUE
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "              return TRUE"
>             }
Error: unexpected '}' in "            }"
>           }
Error: unexpected '}' in "          }"
>         }   
Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"
>       }
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>       
>       if(flag != 1){
+         return FALSE
Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"      if(flag != 1){
        return FALSE"
>       }
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>     }    
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
>   }  
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go aback and read the Intro to R to understand the syntax.  Part of the problem is that 'return' is a function call and you have to have the value in parends.

Also get a text editor that highlights parends and bracket since you were missing some.  Here is a function that is valid:

```
> isomorphic <- function(g1,g2){
+   ##first calculate number of vertices, if not equal, return false
+   if(length(g1) != length(g2)){
+     return( FALSE)
+   ##then compare each vertix and its related edges and weights
+   } else {
+     for(i in 1:length(g1)){
+       for(j in 1:length(g2)){
+         if(names(g1[i]) == names(g2[j])){
+           flag = 1
+           if(g1[[i]]$edges != g2[[j]]$edges){
+               return( FALSE            )
+           } else {
+             if(g1[[i]]$weights != g2[[j]]$weights){
+               return (FALSE)
+             } else {
+               return( TRUE)
+             }
+           }
+         }   
+       }
+ 
+       if(flag != 1){
+         return( FALSE)
+       }
+     }    
+   }  
+ }
>
```